# How does form_with know which method to call inside a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm having a hard time trying to understand how form_with works. To understand most basic usage of form_with, I was looking how Rails set it up in the rails g scaffold process.

I created an equipment scaffold and in it, I looked at how a form was setup in the _form.html.erb file.

```
<%= form_with(model: equipment, local: true) do |form| %>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-10 col-offset-left-1">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= form.label :name %><br />
          <%= form.text_field :name, placeholder: "equipment name", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Turned out I'm still confused how the form knows that this is form should create a new equipment or edit existing equipment? The form only specifies the model but I can't find where the method is specified.

Would someone be able to point me to the right direction? thanks

Answer (score 3):

it's enough to specify the model because the method `form_with` can check if the model (already saved) so it will send patch request or the model is a (new model) so it will send a post request. 
Active record already has some functions to be used to know if the record new or persisted

```
 equipment.new_record? # returns true when the model is new and false if saved 
 equipment. persisted? # returns false when the model is new and true if saved
```

the rails source code here shows that 
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/c87f6841b77e5827ca7bd03a629e2d615fae0d06/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb#L1530 
the method also can know the path of the request easily from the model similar to `path_for`

Answer (score 1):

Your code block:

```
<%= form_with(model: equipment, local: true) do |form| %>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-10 col-offset-left-1">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= form.label :name %><br />
          <%= form.text_field :name, placeholder: "equipment name", class: "form-control" %>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

will render the something like this:

```
<form action=”/equipments” accept-charset=”UTF-8" method=”post” data-remote=”true”>
 <input name=”utf8" type=”hidden” value=”✓”>
 <input type=”hidden” name=”authenticity_token” value=”…”>
 <input type=”text” name=”post[name]”>
 <input type=”submit” name=”commit” value=”Create” data-disable-with=”Create”>
</form>
```

Now, the `form_with` view helper uses, the URL to know what value the `model` is and render the form accordingly.

DHH made an [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/25197) explaining the reason for the introduction of `form_with`